# How to make a date query? (Where = date > 01-01-2011)

Tags: date, where-clause, typo3, typoscript

Is there a way in Typo3 to query the date in an elegant way?
I experimentet with the *tt_content* field *date* and I find out that the date is saved as a 10 character long integer.. I thought it is in an other format.

I would like something like this:

```
10 < styles.content.getLeft
10 {
  select {
    where = date = %y2011 //everything with year 2011
  }
}
```

OR

```
10 < styles.content.getLeft
10 {
  select {
    where = date > 23-1-1996
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, dates are saved as UNIX timestamps so a timestamp needs to be used in the SQL queries. You can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function of MySQL so that you can easily create your query:

```
10 < styles.content.getLeft
10 {
  select {
    where = date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1996-01-23 23:59:59')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

date is saved as unix timestamp in typo3 tables, that's standard way of saving dates, you must just convert unix timestamp to date or date to unix timestamp, in php there is date/strftime function and in typoscript i found quickly this [enter link description here](http://www.jochen-froehlich.de/en/typoscript/current-date.html)

```
temp.current_date = TEXT
temp.current_date {
  data = yourdate (for example 2011) : U
  strftime = %A, %e. %B %Y
}
```

here you convert date to unix timestamp after that you can use temp.current_date in your query

```
select {
    where = date > yourdate
}
```